# Testing callback inside of Promise returning function

Tags: angular, asynchronous, jasmine

I have a method that looks like the following:

```
public async updateData(callback): Promise<any> {
    this.observableOne = this.httpClient.get(...);

    this.observableOne.subscribe(data => {
        // do things...
        callback();
    });
}
```

From my component, I call the following function like this:

```
this.myService.updateData(function() {
    // do more things...
});
```

I'm currently trying to test this function in my Jasmine test and am unsure of how I could wait for the inner Observable to finish before expecting anything.

I normally am able to test a single Promise by doing something like:

```
myService.myPromise.then(data => { expect(data.items).toBeDefined(); });
```

But because the inner Observable is really what I want to wait for before trying to resolve anything, how can I test this callback logic?

I'm trying to do this:

```
myService.updateData(function() {
    // make assertions in here
    // at this point though, is my Promise done and the callback resolved?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to how Angular `async` and `fakeAsync` helpers work, it's expected that a callback can be tested as listed in the question; asynchronous processes are tracked by Zone.js and Jasmine `done` callback is unnecessary. In unit tests, `HttpClient` request should be mocked, so there are no asynchronous processes, and a test can be performed synchronously with `fakeAsync`:

```
it('...', fakeAsync(inject(..., (...) => {
  myService.updateData(function() {
    expect(...)...
  });
});
```

`updateData` is a sort of antipattern because it's a mixture of promises, observables and regular callbacks. Despite it's `async` and returns a promise, it's not actually used. It should be preferably refactored to promises:

```
public async updateData(callback): Promise<any> {
  const data = await this.httpClient.get(...).toPromise();
  ...
  return data;
}
```

And promises are cleaner to test with `async` function:

```
it('...', fakeAsync(inject(..., async (...) => {
  expect(await myService.updateData())...
});
```